# Place View on top of other View in React Native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, css-position

What I want is to display a line (or a View) on top of multiple other Views.

I have tried with `position: absolute`, `z-index` and to write the thing I want on top last in the code. Unfortunately none of these does the trick. How can I get the line on top?

This is what I get:

[image: View above view react native timeline]

This is the code:

```
<ScrollView style={styles.container}>

  <View style={styles.items}>
    {this.state.items.map((item, index) =>
      <View style={styles.item} key={index} elevation={3} />
    }
  </View>

  <View style={styles.line} />

</ScrollView>
```

```css
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1
  },
  row: {
    margin: 10
  },
  line: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 80,
    width: 7,
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ok so I found the problem xD**

Apparently the `elevation={3}` messes it up. Everything works if I simply remove this prop from the row Views.

Comment: not working for me I used ```style={{elevation:1000, zIndex:1000}}```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving the other components a z-index of 0 and the line an index of 1? Also you can try to use a position:fixed property. Hope this helps

Comment: The problem was that I had an `elevation` prop on my rows, it works when I remove it. Don't know if it is a bug but I guess I have to live with it :P

Comment: @howtopythonpls gotcha, You figure a simple z-index would work fine. Cheers

Comment: Yeah but sadly it didn't, tried exactly what you described. The position: fixed is not available in react-native I believe. Thanks anyway :)